# Days of the Week Java Program

Tags: java, while-loop, days

I have a final assignment that I have been stuck on for a bit now and I was looking for help. Currently every criteria is met from the prompt, except for the last portion (sort of) which is to take 2 numerical user inputs and have a while loop bring the total to less than 7. This is because the program I am writing needs to take a user's input and return the day they selected, the day previous to it on the weekly calendar, the following day to the original returned value, and then finally the user is to enter in an amount of days in order find out what the original day is plus X amount of days generates what that day of the week is. I have the code attached. Any good pointers or help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you for taking the time to look at it.

```
//import library
import java.util.*;

//declare the class and make it public
public class Day 
{
//store days of the week
   private static final int SUNDAY = 0;
   private static final int MONDAY = 1;
   private static final int TUESDAY = 2;
   private static final int WEDNESDAY = 3;
   private static final int THURSDAY = 4;
   private static final int FRIDAY = 5;
   private static final int SATURDAY = 6;

//create a new scanner input
   static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

//creates a public method
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      //declare variables
      Day dy = new Day(Day.WEDNESDAY);
      int choice;
      //creates menu varible
      do
      {
         //creates the first selection menu like on page 529
         menu2();
         choice = keyboard.nextInt();
         System.out.println();

         switch (choice)
         {
            case 1:

               do 
               {
                  menu1();
                  choice = keyboard.nextInt();
                  System.out.println();
                  switch (choice)
                  {
                     case 0:
                        day = SUNDAY;
                        break;
                     case 1:
                        day = MONDAY;
                        break;
                     case 2:
                        day = TUESDAY;
                        break;
                     case 3:
                        day = WEDNESDAY;
                        break;
                     case 4:
                        day = THURSDAY;
                        break;
                     case 5:
                        day = FRIDAY;
                        break;
                     case 6:
                        day = SATURDAY;
                        break;
                     case 32: //used 32 since there are only ever 31 days 
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;

                     default:
                        System.out.println("Invalid Input");

                  }
               //output the calculated selections
                  System.out.print("The day you selected is: ");
                  dy.print();
                  System.out.println();

                  System.out.print("The next day is: ");
                  dy.setDay(dy.getNextDay());
                  dy.print();
                  System.out.println();

                  System.out.print("The previous is: ");
                  dy.setDay(dy.getPreviousDay());
                  dy.setDay(dy.getPreviousDay());
                  dy.print();
                  System.out.println();

                  System.out.print("How many days would you like to add (within a month's time)? ");
               //output added days

                  int days = keyboard.nextInt();
                  dy.setDay(days);
                  System.out.print("\nAdding " + days + " day(s) makes your new day: ");
                  while(day > 6)
                  {
                     choice + (day -= 7);
                  }

                  dy.print();
                  System.out.println();


               //program exit

               }
               while (choice != 32);

               break;
         //create a case for the testing method
            case 2:
               System.out.println("Test Data For Day Class");

               System.out.print("\nInitial day: ");
               dy = new Day(Day.SUNDAY);
               dy.print();

               System.out.print("\nNext day: ");
               dy.setDay(dy.getNextDay());
               dy.print();

               System.out.print("\nAdd 12 Days: ");
               dy.setDay(dy.addDays(12));
               dy.print();

               System.out.print("\nPrevious day: ");
               dy.setDay(dy.getPreviousDay());
               dy.print();

               System.out.print("\nAdd 3 days: ");
               dy.setDay(dy.addDays(3));
               dy.print();
               System.out.println("\n\n");

               break;
         //program exit
            case 32:
               System.exit(0);
               break;

            default:
               System.out.println("Invalid Input");
         }

      }
      while (choice != 32);
   }
//output the day selection menu
   public static void menu1()
   {
      System.out.println("Please Select Your Initial Day (or 32 to quit):");
      System.out.println(" 0: Sunday.");
      System.out.println(" 1: Monday.");
      System.out.println(" 2: Tuesday.");
      System.out.println(" 3: Wednesday.");
      System.out.println(" 4: Thursday.");
      System.out.println(" 5: Friday.");
      System.out.println(" 6: Saturday.");
      System.out.println("32: To quit the program.");
   }
//output the type selection menu
   public static void menu2()
   {
      System.out.println("Enter: ");
      System.out.println("1: To Enter Data into the program.");
      System.out.println("2: For Test Data.");
      System.out.println("32: To quit the program.");
   }




  //Stores the day 

   public static int day;


  //Set the day.

   public void setDay(int day) 
   {
      this.day = day;
   }


 //Output the day

   public void print() 
   {
      System.out.println(this.toString());
   }


 //Return the day.

   public int getDay() 
   {

      return day;
   }


//Return the next day.

   public int getNextDay() {
      return (day + 1) % 7;
   }
//override for the days of the week
   @Override
   public String toString() {
      switch (Day.day) {
         case SUNDAY:
            return "Sunday";
         case MONDAY:
            return "Monday";
         case TUESDAY:
            return "Tuesday";
         case WEDNESDAY:
            return "Wednesday";
         case THURSDAY:
            return "Thursday";
         case FRIDAY:
            return "Friday";
         case SATURDAY:
            return "Saturday";
      }
      return "";
   }


  //Return the previous day.

   public int getPreviousDay() 
   {
      if (day == 0)
         return (day + 6) % 7;
      else
         return (day - 1) % 7;
   }


 //Calculate and return the day by adding days

   public int addDays(int days) 
   {

      return (day += days);
   }


   //Add the constructors.

   public Day() 
   {
      this.day = SUNDAY;
   }

   public Day(int day)
   {
      this.day = day;
   }
}
```

Comment: Just so you know, you don't need a `while` loop to count days. `(startDay + daysToAdd) % 7` will give you the DOW `daysToAdd` after `startDay`.

Answer (score 1):

Just as @cHao said, you could easily do this using the [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) (or [remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder)) operator (%).

```
x = (x + y) % 7
```